# Preserving input filter activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to keep my inputs in my filter in activeadmin here my code:

```
controller do
    before_filter by_resolved_at_in: :index do
      if params[:q][:by_resolved_at_in_gteq].blank?
          params[:q][:by_resolved_at_in_gteq] = params[:q][:by_resolved_at_in_gteq]
    end
end
```

but this doesnot work. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need, but because of the question I think that when working with ***ActiveAdmin*** it automatically creates a filter for each of your model attributes but **if you add a custom filter** all of them are taken away.

So, If you want to preserve the automatic created ones along with yours, maybe adding this line could solve the problem.

```
preserve_default_filters!
```

Let me know if this was your question.